# is it possible to make gunicorn to reuse pid when workers restart?

Tags: gunicorn, prometheus

I have troubles with prometheus's multiprocess mode (`MultiProcessCollector`): every time when gunicron worker restarts (eg on timeout) it starts with new pid and because of this prometheus creates new file for storing metrics. But when metrics are collected prometheus client checks **all** files. After a day in production my `/metrics/` endpoint can respond as slow as 2s (and even more).

Prometheus documentation says that it is not safe to delete metrics file, but I have an idea to delete these files only if they where not updated for some time (eg 2 minutes), meaning that associated worker is already dead. On do this in `child_exit` gunicorn's hook. But I fear that prometheus will lose some data after the wipe, but on the other hand it still knows about latest counter after application restart, so this part is questionable.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the Python Prometheus client library. See this issue https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/issues/568 for example. I'd say go for it. Also consider dropping Gunicorn alltogether and instead relying on Uvicorn and container replicas.